# How to avoid import function from Module

Tags: swift, swift-compiler

I have two Packages: `FirstModule` and `AnotherModule`, and each of them defines

```
extension CGPoint {
    public static func + (lhs: CGPoint, rhs: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        CGPoint(x: lhs.x + rhs.x, y: lhs.y+rhs.y)
    }
}
```

Also in main app I defined

```
extension CGPoint {
#if !canImport(FirstModule) && !canImport(AnotherModule)
    public static func + (lhs: CGPoint, rhs: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        CGPoint(x: lhs.x + rhs.x, y: lhs.y + rhs.y)
    }
...
#endif
}
```

and some class in another file:

```
#import FirstModule 
#import AnotherModule

class Whatever() {
    ///Uses CGPoint + CGPoint
}
```

Unfortunately, compiler throws an error: `Ambiguous use of operator '+'` and point on both imported modules.
Not all classes in my app use `FirstModule` and `AnotherModule` but they need just `func + ()`

How to avoid import `func + ()` from `FirstModule` and `AnotherModule` in `Whatever` class?

Comment: So in that file, you are using things from both modules, but are also trying to use `CGPoint.+`? Are they implemented in the same way? Or are you trying to use a specific module's implementation?

Comment: In one of them labels are different `static func + (left: CGPoint, right: CGPoint)`. Expected result is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One potential way to do this is to explicitly import everything you are using from one of the modules.

You can explicitly import typealiases, structs, classes, enums, protocols, global `let`s, `var`s and functions.

Example:

```
import typealias FirstModule.SomeTypeAlias
import struct FirstModule.SomeStruct
import class FirstModule.SomeClass
import enum FirstModule.SomeEnum
import protocol FirstModule.SomeProtocol
import let FirstModule.someGlobalConstant
import var FirstModule.someGlobalVar
import func FirstModule.someGlobalFunction
import AnotherModule

// now you will use the CGPoint.+ from AnotherModule
```

Note that you cannot explicitly import extensions or operators. If you need extensions or operators (that are not `CGPoint.+`) from `FirstModule`, I would suggest that you move those to another file with only `import FirstModule`.

(Needless to say, you should replace `FirstModule` with the module from which you are using *fewer* members)